# jQuery getJSON, получение данных из файла в той же папке

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$.getJSON('1.json',
function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
);
```

Должен ли работать такой скрипт, если файл html, в котором это написано, находится в одной папке с 1.json?

Comment: Да. А если у вас что-то не работает, то загляните в консоль.

Comment: @Deonis вот пытаюсь понять, в чем дело, через firebug, но там совсем пусто, никаких ошибок

Comment: Ответ на запрос наблюдаете?

Comment: @Юрий, а json проверяли? Он валиден?

Comment: Кстати, да... По поводу валидности и за что я так не люблю shorthand-методы: *As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.*

Comment: @nuts119 Всем спасибо) Он пустой был, теперь все работает)

Comment: @Юрий,  Улыбнуло :)

Comment: @Юрий А что в DevTools в закладке Network не видно было что он пустой? Ух ты :-)

Comment: @BearGRiZZLYXi А где такая закладка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала открываем **DevTools**(*Chrome, YandexBrowser, Opera>12.18, Amigo, Vivaldi and etc на движке Chromium*) клавишей **F12**

1. Закладка Network - Здесь все общение с сетью (XHR===AJAX, и остальные файлы Вебсокеты и т.д.)
2. Запрос к серверу на получение комментария
3. Адрес, куда стучимся полный появляется при наведении(но можно включить в панели выше отображение сразу полного пути значок рядом со словом [View:] думаю найдете :-) )
4. **XHR** - фильтр запросам на сервер AJAX(getJSON and atc)
5. Preview - это закладка, в которой отображается ответ от сервера.
6. А это тот самый ответ от сервера.

[image: Снимок Экрана]